# Are there any online SQL interpreters with working databases for free?

Tags: sql, resources

I'm looking for a **free** online SQL interpreter that also has a database associated with it.  I want to play around with SQL statements, but I don't want to setup my own database.  I've looked around google for a bit, but I only found one web site that has interactive courses, an interpreter functionality and a small database: http://sqlcourse2.com/

Does anybody know of a better SQL interpreter and database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle offers free hosted workspaces for evaluation at [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com).

Answer (score 4):

SQLite is the fastest way to go. 
http://www.sqlite.org/

It is supplied with a command-line utility to execute queries.
The database is kept in a single .sqlite3 file.
As simplistic as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

My only advice is that if you're going to learn SQL it would be worth learning also how to install the thing. Most DBAs I know are also fairly adept systems administrators as well and for good reason. Setting up real databases can be difficult to do well.

So go out and get a copy of an easy DB with a good ui and get started. If you're on the mac you already have MySQL and you can use Sequel Pro as the UI. If you're on windows I'd really recommend PostgresQL and the excellent PgAdmin.

SQL isn't just syntax anymore, I know the spec says otherwise but if you're interested in learning about databases for a job just groking the syntax isn't enough.

Comment: @Chuck I need it more to try some quick queries... I don't do much with databases.  I work with databases so infrequently that installing it is an inconvenience, I re-install my OS more often than I install databases.  I do get your point tho :).

Answer (score 2):

I've used and recommended this site before to friends.

http://www.sql-ex.ru

It has exercises that you write SQL for and test on a live database. They also have decent faq's, guides, forum discussion based on exercises, ect... Pretty good source if you are starting up or want to test your skills or see more then one way to approach a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to set up a database? It is quick and easy to do.

Check the [Express version of SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/). It is also free.

SQL Server Express WebLog: [How should I Install SQL Server 2008 Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/06/15/installing-sql-server-2008-guidance.aspx)

Comment: I reinstall my OS more often than I install a DB.  Sometimes I just need to experiment with simple queries, so installing a DB just for that is just not worth it for me.

Comment: use a virtual instance and start it up when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using sqleditor.co.uk to teach my students basic SQL.
According to help page it is using MySQL backend.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MySQL](http://bluesql.net/) free hosting here.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Ideone](http://ideone.com) - it is free and supports SSQLite

Answer (score 0):

I found link where you can directly try queries online:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp

Comment: @Richard, I'm not sure, but it's cool that it we can run queries online.